# NavigationBar and View with different background color

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uinavigationbar

I have a UIView with UINavigationBar.

I'm building this code to setting background color at View and also at NavigationBar.

So this is the code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = getColor(red: 41, green: 151, blue: 255)
       self.view.backgroundColor = getColor(red: 41, green: 151, blue: 255)      
    }

func getColor(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) ->
   UIColor{
   return UIColor(red: CGFloat(Float(red) / 255.0),
      green CGFloat(Float(red) / 255.0),
      blue: CGFloat(Float(red) / 255.0),
      alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
}
```

As you can see the color is the same, but the output view is like this:

[image]

As you can see, the NavBar have the different color and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

instead of

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = getColor(red: 41, green: 151, blue: 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to set the navigation bar's `isTranslucent` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your navigation bar is translucent, try settings `isTranslucent` to false.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is because of navigation bar `isTranslucent`, set it programmatically to `false` or if you're using storyboard it could be done by removing the check from Translucent like the photo attached.

[image]